# How to avoid the consecutive hyphenation in a para

Tags: paragraphs, hyphenation, penalty

i am getting the consecutive hyphen at the line end in a paragraph (more than 5 consecutive hyphen), in a two column format, I already used \doublehyphendemerits=10000, but not solved the issue.

how to avoid the consecutive hyphenation through automation

Comment: 10000 is the default value, needs to be much higher to suppress them

Comment: If you are getting 5 consecutive hyphens are you sure there is any setting at all that has less hyphens and fits in the width, even if you increase the demerits to the maximum?

Answer (score 1):

10000 is the default value, demerits are "badness squared" so need to have twice as many digits or simply use `\maxdimen` which a suitably large integer value.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox{3cm}{%
conveniently extravagant vocabulary to maximise hyphenation possibilities in exceptionally narrow text
conveniently extravagant vocabulary to maximise hyphenation possibilities in exceptionally narrow text
}}


\fbox{%
\doublehyphendemerits=\maxdimen
\parbox{3cm}{%
conveniently extravagant vocabulary to maximise hyphenation possibilities in exceptionally narrow text
conveniently extravagant vocabulary to maximise hyphenation possibilities in exceptionally narrow text
}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But as shown here the text isn't pretty in either case and a ragged setting requiring fewer hyphens would usually be preferable.